# Append row to dataset in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new dataset deleting some rows (trough a comparison with a dataset ds1) from ds2. I wrote a function that should do this:

```
compare<-function(ds1,ds2){
for(i in 1:length(ds1$long)){
    for(j in 1:length(ds2$long)){
        if(ds1$long[i]<(ds2$long[j]+500) & ds1$long[i]>(ds2$long[j]-500)){
            if(ds1$lat[i]<(ds2$lat[j]+500) & ds1$lat[i]>(ds2$lat[j]-500)){
                ds3<-data.frame(merge(ds2[j,],ds3))
            }
        }
    }
}
return(ds3) 
}
```

ds3 is the dataset I want to return, it should be formed by the rows of the original dataset ds2 that satisfy the condition above. 
My function gives me an error:

```
Error in as.data.frame(y) : 
argument "y"  is not specified and has not a definite value
```

Is "merge()" the right function for creating such a dataset, appending rows to ds3?
If not, which is the right function to do this?

Thank you all in advance

Edit: I modified the function thanks to your tips, using

```
ds3<-data.frame()
ds3<-rbind(ds3,ds2[j,])
```

instead of

```
ds3<-data.frame(merge(ds2[j,],ds3))
```

Now I've got this error:

```
Errore in rbind(ds3, ds2[j, ]) : 
no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

If I use rbind(), can I operate with SpatialPoints? (data contained in my dataset are spatial points)

Edit2: I have 2 datasets, one with 330 rows (points on irregular grid, ds1), one with ~150000 rows (points on regular grid, ds2). I want to compute correlation between the variables in the first dataset and the variables in the second one. For making it, I want to "reduce" the second dataset to the dimensions of the first, saving only the points which have the same coordinates (or quasi) in both datasets.

Comment: Try using `rbind` instead of `merge`

Comment: initialize `ds3` and use `rbind`.

Comment: Step 1:  subset ds1 with `[` by conditions Step 2 `rbind` There shouldn't be any looping necessary by the looks of it.  Please clarify the question with data examples and desired result

Comment: Richard Scriven: thank you, edited my question with the result I'd like to find. I didn't understand your tip good, how can I do without a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a small example this has no testing but if you are happy with the performance of the for-loop then this may be what you are attempting:

```
compare<-function(ds1,ds2){
for(i in 1:length(ds1$long)){
    for(j in i:length(ds2$long)){   # I think starting at 1 will give twice as many hits
        if(ds1$long[i]<(ds2$long[j]+500) & ds1$long[i]>(ds2$long[j]-500)){
            if(ds1$lat[i]<(ds2$lat[j]+500) & ds1$lat[i]>(ds2$lat[j]-500)){
               if( length(d3) ) { # check to see if d3 exists or not
                ds3<-rbind( ds3, ds2[,j] ) } else {  # append as the next row
                d3 <- ds2[ ,j] }   # should only get executed once
            }
        }
    }
}
return(ds3) 
}
```

I tried to avoid the added overhead of retesting for j,i matches where you already had an i,j match. Again, I cannot tell for sure this is appropriate because the problem description still is not exactly clear to me.

Comment: Signed your answer as correct because of the patience to write some code and read the problem. I've again some problems but you're answer is useful.